# Ruby#index Method VS Binary Search

Tags: ruby, indexing, binary-search

Given an element and an array, the Ruby#index method returns the position of the element in the array. I implemented my own index method using binary search expecting mine would outperform the built-in one. To my surprise, the built-in one ran approximately three times as fast as mine in an experiment.

Any Rubyist knows the reason why?

Comment: Who said the Ruby `#index` method was not already implemented with binary search? And furthermore, who said that method was implemented in Ruby at all? :-)

Comment: @Platinum Azure Oh I see, it might be implemented in C with binary search. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The built-in [`#index` is not a binary search](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/array.c#L1346), it's just a simple iterative search. However, it is implemented in C rather than Ruby, so naturally it can be several orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Thanks. That's really weird, though. Was there a reason why they didn't adopt the binary search approach?

Comment: A binary search involves being able to compare two elements, as opposed to just being able to see if two elemnts are equal. Also notice the documentation says it returns the *first* object equal to the argument — a binary search would not always return that element. Besides, my version of #bsearch (assuming the array is sorted) doesn't seem slower than #index: https://gist.github.com/1220440

Comment: I assume your #bsearch implementation is able to beat the difference between Ruby and C with that between binary search and sequential search?

Comment: A binary search also requires a sorted array, which is O(n log n) - so if #index "knew" it was to be called enough times, that would be worth doing, but not in the general case.

Comment: @jkebinger  True. I forgot to mention that my array be a sorted one. Thanks for your input!

Comment: Thanks @LBg, I couldn't figure out how to get it to link directly to the line. I wonder why they don't just use `...#1171` ?