# Is there a built-in binary-search In Ruby?

Tags: ruby, binary-search

I am looking for a built-in Ruby method that has the same functionality as `index` but uses a binary search algorithm, and thus requires a pre-sorted array.

I know I could write my own implementation, but according to "[Ruby#index Method VS Binary Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436155/rubyindex-method-vs-binary-search)", the built-in simple iterative search used by index is faster than a pure-Ruby version of binary search, since the built-in method is written in C.

Does Ruby provide any built-in methods that do binary search?

Comment: No need to write your own: [tyler/binary_search](https://github.com/tyler/binary_search). The author has also taken the time to run some benchmarks.

Comment: Hi sczizzo, I am new to ruby so this is a pretty newb question, but how do I add this functionality to my ruby installation?  Is it just a matter of running the rakefile?  Thanks.

Comment: Might be easier to use the `bsearch` gem, as Marc-André suggested. Then it's pretty much as simple as `gem install bsearch` on the command line, and `require 'bsearch'` in your Ruby. You might want to [look at the documentation for usage](http://rubydoc.info/gems/bsearch/1.5.0/frames).

Comment: It should be noted that even if it is written in ruby any implementation of a binary search will eventually outperform any implementation of linear search, no matter how optimized, for large enough arrays.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Ruby 2.0 introduced [`Array#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) and [`Range#bsearch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#method-i-bsearch).

For Ruby 1.9, you should look into the [`bsearch`](http://rubygems.org/gems/bsearch) and [`binary_search`](https://github.com/tyler/binary_search) gems.
Other possibility is to use a different collection than an array, like [using `rbtree`](http://rubygems.org/gems/rbtree)

`bsearch` is in my [`backports` gem](https://github.com/marcandre/backports), but this is a pure Ruby version, so quite a bit slower. Note that a pure Ruby binary search will still be faster than a linear builtin search like `index` or `include?` for big enough arrays/ranges (or expensive comparisons), since it's not the same order of complexity `O(log n)` vs `O(n)`.

To play with it today, you can `require 'backports/2.0.0/array/bsearch'` or `require 'backports/2.0.0/range/bsearch'`.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Marc, Thanks for the answer.  Are there any 3rd party libraries (written in C) that I could use?

Comment: And @sczizzo linked to another gem too.

Comment: Note that Array#bsearch has now been merged into Ruby: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4766#change-32923

Comment: Will this be faster than "include?" which seems to be a linear search?

Comment: @Rahul: Yes, `Array#include?` is linear so will be slower.

Comment: Is there a way to return the index instead of the value?

Comment: That's a different question... Post separately and comment back here?

Comment: I just tried this on Ruby 2.2.2 and would like to note it doesn't work with ranges of characters. Ex. ('a'..'z').bsearch {|letter| letter == 'b'} fails w/ "TypeError: can't do binary search for String"

Comment: @frankpinto You actually can, but you need to convert that range to an array first, and use >= rather than ==. This works: ('a'..'z').to_a.bsearch { |letter| letter >= 'b' }

Answer (score 12):

A lot has changed since 2011, in Ruby 2.3, you can use `bsearch_index`

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch_index

`array.bsearch_index { |val| query <=> val }`

Comment: What's wrong with this?

`arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e']`
`arr.sort.bsearch { |x| 'a' == x }`

Comment: @AHK try arr.sort.bsearch{ |x| 'a' <=> x }

Answer (score 3):

I use `bsearch`. This is how it works:

```
array = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']

search = array.sort.bsearch { |value| 'four' <=> value }
```

Note: binary search needs a sorted array; this adds a li'l overhead but it's fine, compared to the speed of the search.

`search` will return the value `four` of the `array`, else `nil` if it doesn't find the value.