# Ruby Array #bsearch syntax error from Programming Ruby?

Tags: ruby, bsearch

Copying this code from book Programming Ruby and running it in rubyfiddle.com . Getting syntax error instead of # => 21​ ? Any help is appreciated!

```
arr = [ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34 ]
res = arr.bsearch ​do​ |val|
  ​case​
​    ​when​ val < 19 ​then​ +1
​   ​when​ val > 23 ​then​ -1
​   ​else​ 0
​  end​  ​  
​end​
​   
res ​# => 21​
```

Comment: What is the exact syntax error?

Comment: @Pavan Output

SyntaxError:

Comment: Could you just copy the error or error line and post it in your question please.

Comment: @Pavan (eval):48: undefined method `bsearch' for [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]:Array (NoMethodError)  => I get this error in labs.codecademy.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672472/is-there-a-built-in-binary-search-in-ruby

Comment: What is the version of your Ruby?

Comment: The code is weirdly written and even more weirdly formatted, but I don't see any syntax error in the code. Please provide the *exact* code that is giving you the syntax error, tell us *which line* the error occurs on and provide the *exact* error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having tested your code myself, there is nothing wrong with what you have written. In all likelihood you (or in this case, codecademy) are using an older version of Ruby. The `bsearch` method was defined on [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch) and [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html#method-i-bsearch) in Ruby 2.0. Prior to Ruby 2.0, there were several gems that could be used to perform a binary search on an array.

To test which version of Ruby you are using, type the following into `irb` or your codecademy console:

```
> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.1.1"
```

If the number returned is less than `"2.0"`, `bsearch` will not be natively defined for either `Array` or `Range`

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes it does, if you read the OP's comments, the error was `undefined method 'bsearch' for [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]:Array(NoMethodError)`

Answer (score 0):

As you specified in one of your comment the exact error is:

```
(eval):48: undefined method `bsearch' for [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]:Array (NoMethodError)
```

This error means the method `bsearch` doesn't exist for `Array`.

---

In [labs.codecademy.com](http://labs.codecademy.com/)

```
 > RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
```

There is no `bsearch` in [`Ruby 1.8.7`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html).
`bsearch` has been implemented in [`Ruby 2.0`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-bsearch).

Comment: The exact error, as specified in one of the comment by @user3222947 is `(eval):48: undefined method 'bsearch' for [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]:Array (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I added the specified error in my answer.

Comment: That's not a syntax error (`SyntaxError`), that's a semantic error (`NoMethodError`). The OP mentioned three times that he is getting a syntax error as well, *that's* what I am puzzled by. The `NoMethodError` is obvious.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, You have it. The `syntax error` in the question only means `error`. Then the error should have been specified as well in the question but is only written in the comment section. There are many misleading mistakes here.