# How to remove range from an array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find something equivalent to `remove_range` (which does not exist of course) as shown below. Seems there is no easy way to implement this functionality.

```
a = [0,2,8,2,4,5,]
b = a.remove_range(1,2) #remove items between index 1 and 2 ,inclusively
#expect b == [0,2,4,5]
b = a.remove_range(3,4)
#expect b == [0,2,8,5]
```

**Please test at least above two cases before posting your solution :)**

Suppose the size of the range is M, this operation should requires O(1) space and O(N-M) time complexity.

EDIT:
I see people keep posting the `a - a[range]`. But it is not correct, that is to remove the elements exists in a[range], not to remove the the element belongs to range.

`a - a[1..2]`  will return `[0, 4, 5]`. However,we want to keep the 3rd element which is `2`.

Comment: Is a Ruby API/grammar question or a coding/algorithm question?

Comment: I disagree that it "does not exist."  It's just not named what you think it is.

Comment: +David Hoelzer I'm happy to know it is there. What is the name?

Comment: In your example, `a` never changes, that means you have to copy the result to another array, right? Then how to achieve O(1) space complexity?

Comment: @coderz you are right. There maybe simply no way to achieve O(1) with Ruby. I was just trying to set that as a target, which can be achieved in c/c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do some cool tricks with the Enumerable module:

```
a = [0, 2, 8, 2, 4, 5]
r = 1..2
a.reject.with_index { |v, i| r.include?(i) }  # => [0, 2, 4, 5]
```

Note that this does not modify the original array, but returns a new one.  You can  use `reject!` if you want to modify the array.

Comment: this is tricky, I didn't know the `.reject.with_index` stuff. Cool one.

Comment: I hear someone saying, "Why didn't Grayson use [Range#cover](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F)? instead of [Range#include](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F)?, which checks each element in the range?".  Ah, but  `include?` is smart enough to know that, like `cover?`, it can just use the endpoints when, as here, they are numeric.

Comment: Worked nicely for me!

Answer (score 2):

```
# Use: array.slice!(range)
a = [0,2,8,2,4,5,]

a.slice!(1..2)
a # => [0, 2, 4, 5]
```

Or for indices range 3 to 4

```
a.slice!(3..4)
a # => [0, 2, 8, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is built into the array class.  Just subtract the piece that you don't want:

```
2.0.0-p353 :001 > ar = [0,2,8,2,4,5]
=> [0, 2, 8, 2, 4, 5] 
2.0.0-p353 :002 > ar - ar[2..3]
=> [0, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def remove_range(sp, ep)
    raise ArgumentError if sp < 0 || ep > size - 1
    slice(0...sp).concat(slice(ep+1..-1))
  end
end
```

Thank Cary Swoveland for his good advise

Comment: You may wish to raise an `ArgumentError` exception rather than returning `false`. The rest could alternatively be expressed  `slice(0...sp).concat(slice(ep+1..-1))`. `Array#concat` is more efficient than `+` because it avoids the creation of two temporary arrays.

Comment: A small point: when an `if` statement has just one line between `if` and `end`, some prefer writing (for example): `raise ArgumentError  if sp < 0 || ep > size - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Array
  def remove_range(f,l)
    self[0..f-1].concat(self[l+1..-1])
  end
end

a = [0,2,8,2,4,5]
b = a.remove_range(1,2)
[0, 2, 4, 5]
c = a.remove_range(3,4)
[0, 2, 8, 5]
```

Comment: Yeah, I think it is the most straightforward (not the coolest) way  :)

Comment: @pierr Beware the `+`, though, unless your arrays are always short.

Comment: Updated + to concat based on @DaveNewton note

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0,2,8,2,4,5]    
j = 1

(3..4).each do |i|
    j == 1 ? a.delete_at(i) : a.delete_at(i-1)
    j += 1
end

b = a
[0, 2, 8, 5]
```

Comment: `delete_at` operation is O(n) time complexity(see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510123/ruby-delete-a-value-from-sorted-unique-array-at-olog-n-runtime), disobey the time complexity requirement.

Comment: If you wish to delete elements, you must delete at the same index so many times or delete by index from highest to lowest index. Note that mutates the array.

Answer (score 0):

Tried something funky with string manipulation. I think it's O(4*M) though if that's even a thing!

```
a.join.gsub(/#{a.join[1..2]}/,'').split('').map{|i| i.to_i}
=> [0, 2, 4, 5]
a.join.gsub(/#{a.join[3..4]}/,'').split('').map{|i| i.to_i}
=> [0, 2, 8, 5]
```