# time complexity of arr.delete() in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, time-complexity

```
arr = [5, 6, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3]
```

Delete all occurrences of a given element

```
arr.delete(5) 
#  => [6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3]
```

What is the time complexity of the above Ruby code and how it works internally?

Comment: You can find out how it works by looking at [the source code](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-delete). Click on the description and the source will be displayed.

Comment: That only tells you the behavior for one specific version of one specific implementation of Ruby. It doesn't tell you anything about Rubinius, TruffleRuby, MagLev, Topaz, JRuby, or MRuby, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete) runs in O(n). You can click on the "click to toggle source" button next to a function in the Ruby documentation to see its implementation:

```
               VALUE
rb_ary_delete(VALUE ary, VALUE item)
{
    VALUE v = item;
    long i1, i2;

    for (i1 = i2 = 0; i1 < RARRAY_LEN(ary); i1++) {
        VALUE e = RARRAY_AREF(ary, i1);

        if (rb_equal(e, item)) {
            v = e;
            continue;
        }
        if (i1 != i2) {
            rb_ary_store(ary, i2, e);
        }
        i2++;
    }
    if (RARRAY_LEN(ary) == i2) {
        if (rb_block_given_p()) {
            return rb_yield(item);
        }
        return Qnil;
    }

    ary_resize_smaller(ary, i2);

    return v;
}
```

As you can see, the function iterates over the array only once.

Comment: then what will be the complexity for deleting a single element in the middle of the array

Comment: I think it still has to check all of the elements in the array before it stops because it needs to make sure there are no other instances of that. You might be looking for [``Array#delete_at``](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) which takes an index. So if you search for the first instance of the element in the array (which will take ``i`` loop cycles where ``i`` is the position of the element in the array), you can then delete that single element.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) . so is it still o(n) to delete an element at specified position for example arr.delete_at(3)

Comment: I was about to say that ``Array#delete_at`` ran in O(1) but it actually runs longer than that, per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510123/ruby-delete-a-value-from-sorted-unique-array-at-olog-n-runtime). It has to shift all of the rest of the data over, so it will still run in the same runtime. It appears that deleting (an) element(s) from an array in Ruby will always run in at least O(n).

Answer (score 2):

There are several different locations where the behavior of Ruby is specified:

- The [Ruby Spec Suite](https://github.com/ruby/spec/),
- The [ISO/IEC 30170:2012 Ruby Programming Language Specification](http://iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=59579),
- [*The Ruby Programming Language* by David Flanagan and Yukihiro Matsumoto](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516178.do),
- [The Ruby Documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/),
- and matz's brain.

Unfortunately, we cannot read the last one, but we can look at all the other ones, and none of them specifies any performance requirements for `Array#delete`:

- The Ruby Spec Suite for `Array#delete`: [`core/array/delete_spec.rb`](https://github.com/ruby/spec/blob/master/core/array/delete_spec.rb) only specifies the return values and exceptions, no performance requirements.
- The ISO Ruby Programming Language Specification doesn't specify `Array#delete` at all (it only specifies a minimal subset of Ruby, and an even more minimal subset of the core library; the standard library is left out completely).
- The Ruby Programming Language doesn't mention `Array#delete` either in section 3.3 *Arrays* nor in section 9.5.2 *Arrays*.
- [The Ruby Documentation for `Array#delete`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-delete) doesn't say anything about performance.

However, there is another thing we can consider: the common sense expectations of the Ruby community. In general, anything in Ruby which violates the Ruby community's common sense expectations of how it should behave is simply not going to get accepted. So, what can we expect from an `Array#delete` method?

- It has to look at all elements of the `Array`, so it cannot possibly be faster than O(n), where n is the size of the array.
- The naive approach would delete all occurrences individually, needing to shift all subsequent elements, which is an O(n) operation executed O(d) times, so the naive approach is O(d*n), where d is the number of occurrences of the item to delete.

So, we know that we cannot get better than O(n), and we know that even the most naive implementation is O(d*n). In other words: you have to be extra clever to be even slower than O(d*n), and we will assume that nobody would do that on purpose.

Therefore, we can conclude that the actual performance of `Array#delete` is somewhere between O(n) (the best possible case) and O(d*n) (the simplest, most naive case).

We could, of course, look at one of the implementations, e.g. [Rubinius](http://rubinius.com/)'s is in [`core/array.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/array.rb#L635-L666), and you can see that it actually collects the items first and then shrinks the array in one step, thus making it O(n).

[Topaz](http://docs.topazruby.com/)'s implementation is in [`lib-topaz/array.rb`](https://github.com/topazproject/topaz/blob/master/lib-topaz/array.rb#L137-L149). It actually just delegates to [`Array#delete_if`](https://github.com/topazproject/topaz/blob/master/lib-topaz/array.rb#L118-L135), which also is O(n) by collecting all deletions first and then resizing the array in one go.

[JRuby](http://JRuby.org/)'s implementation is in [`core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyArray.java`](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyArray.java#L2608-L2653) and also uses the optimization to avoid being O(d*n).

But, this only tells you how that specific version of that specific implementation behaves right now. It doesn't tell you anything about future or past versions, it doesn't tell you anything about other implementations. The only thing you can rely is the specifications (which don't say anything) and common sense.